# DISPLAY variable changed after restart for remote debugging

Tags: ssh, qt, x11-forwarding

I am trying to remotely debug a Qt application. Yesterday everything was fine. the result of `echo $DISPLAY` was something like `localhost:10` and I could see the remote application window in my local system (after putting that in environment variables of qt application).

Now after coming back to office, I see that $DISPLAY is now just `:0` and when I start the remote application it window appears in the remote machine and not in my local machine.

Any idea why this happened (I just turned off things yesterday and turned them back on today!) and any possible fix?`

**UPDATE**

If I use `ssh -X user@ip` on my local machine and call the binary of the application from my terminal, it will show up as a GUI window on my local machine. This is working fine!

The problem is if I do the same thing in qt-creator on my local machine, then the GUI will show up in the remote machine's screen! NOT my local machines screen!

This was working fine yesterday...I had `localhost:10` on as the $DISPLAY variable and I have no idea why it has been changed now.

Comment: *"remotely debug"* how, exactly? if you are using SSH, did you remember to add the `-X` option?

Comment: @steeldriver please see my update

Comment: It looks like you may need to manually configure the tunnel as described here: [How to remotely debug graphic application with QtCreator?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47890131)

Comment: @steeldriver You were right...It seems that I should manually at least once do "ssh -X" on my local terminal before even bothering with QT!!! Do you know why?